# Maxima: Colorplot of 2D scalar field f(x,y) (aka "bird's view")

Tags: plot, maxima

In maxima, the default behavior when invoking the `plot3d()` function is to show the resulting manifold from the side in perspective. For instance, running

```
(%i0) wxplot3d(cos(x)*cos(y),[x,-%pi,%pi],[y,-%pi,%pi]);
```

yields

[image: Maxima's default behaviour is to show the plot from the side.]

Such plots can be very pretty but tend to biaise our interpretation of it and also sometimes parts of the manifold are hidden. How do I get a "bird's view" of the same plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by asking Maxima to run gnuplot's `set view map` command before drawing the plot. Indeed, calling

```
(%i0) wxplot3d(cos(x)*cos(y),[x,-%pi,%pi],[y,-%pi,%pi], [gnuplot_preamble, "set view map"]);
```

yields

[image]

An alternative to the color plot is the contour plot. For instance,

```
(%i1) wxplot3d(cos(x)*cos(y),[x,-%pi,%pi],[y,-%pi,%pi], [gnuplot_preamble,
    "set view map; set size square;unset surface;set contour;set cntrparam levels 10;set clabel '%.1f';set isosamples 150"])
```

yields

[image]

Those parameters are the ones recommended by the "Gnuplot in Action" book, page 145, Listing 8.1. Here is a description of what each does (from the very same listing):

```
set view map            #Choose birds-eye view
set size square         #Choose equal units in both directions
unset surface           #Switch off the surface...
set contour             #... but switch on contours lines
set cntrparam levels 10 #Increase the number of contour lines
set clabel "%.1f"       #Choose format of contour labels in key
set isosamples 150      #Increase sampling frequency
```